# Why does groovysh require X display?

Tags: linux, groovy

I downloaded groovy binary 2.3.9 on Linux. After unzip the package, I ran

```
export GROOVY_HOME=<groovy install dir>
export PATH=$GROOVY_HOME:$PATH
```

I launched groovysh. (I am using JDK1.7)

Groovysh will hang.  Please advise.

Update:

It was X DISPLAY variable problem.
I got it working by

```
export DISPLAY= my ip address :0
```

But why does it require X DISPLAY? Isn't it a terminal program?

Comment: I noticed I can get Groovy shell by running grails shell. But it is not always handy to do that. It requires a grails app to be created first.

Comment: Try `./groovysh --debug`

Comment: ./groovysh --debug
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.BufferManager] Created new buffer with index: 0
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.BufferManager] Buffers reset
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Parser] Using parser flavor: rigid

Comment: Try other `groovey` version and see, also you can try `binary` version

Comment: Problem is solved. See my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not the problem of groovy but of java.  if you have to have a `DISPLAY` set to something wrong and still want to use cli java tools, you could set headless mode.  e.g.

```
DISPLAY=willfail JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true groovysh
```

Comment: Yes. This works. It would be nice if groovysh internally set java.awt.headless to be true though.

Comment: i am not sure if it's the case, but i guess, this would also prevent use of the groovysh to run code from frameworks, that actually need a display (if you want the shell as a REPL to do swing stuff e.g.)

Comment: I also noticed that The DISPLAY issue didn't prevent grails shell from running groovy shell successfully though not sure why.